# how to select grease pencil layers via python？

Tags: python, grease-pencil

[image]

how to select grease pencil layers via python？

Comment: What is your goal?

Answer (score 2):

You can access grease pencil layers into `Object.data.layers`, and define the active layer with `Object.data.layers.active` :

```
import bpy 
   
gp = bpy.context.object
if gp.type == 'GPENCIL' :
    my_layer = gp.data.layers[0]
    gp.data.layers.active = my_layer
```

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning could select by index, reducing last two lines to  `gp.data.layers.active_index = 0`  or by name `gp.data.layers.active = gp.data.layers["OL"]`

Comment: This is not the same as selecting. This is setting the active layer. Selecting would allow for multiple selected layers in the Dopesheet. Each GreasePencilLayer has a property called `select` however it does not change the selected state of the object when using it as such: `bpy.context.object.data.layers["GP_Layer"].select = True`. It is not read only. I believe this is a bug. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.GPencilLayer.html#bpy.types.GPencilLayer.select